# Continous data pass between forms

Tags: c#, image, charts

I have a MainForm that receives images from a camera (15-20 FPS) and extracts data from those images. I want to be able to plot those data, thus I need a `Chart` object that would update on each frame received.

Unfortunately, the API from the camera (Vimba) I am using is, I think, *strangely* written, and I can't draw the `Chart` in the same event that handles the reception of the frames and the extraction of the data. It just doesn't work (in the API, any instruction that involves a graphic object but isn't simply putting the received image in a `Bitmap`, or putting said bitmap into a `PictureBox`, doesn't run, I don't know why).

I have been fighting with this issue for a few days already, and one thing I haven't tried yet is passing the data extracted from the image to another `Form`, and draw the chart there. My problem is that I have no clue how to get the data to be sent to the new form on each frame received. I have already used a simple method to send data to another `Form` ONCE, but not continuously. Could someone explain to me how to achieve this?

Here is the event that runs when the computer receives a frame from the camera (the data I want to draw is stored in `PixelColorCOuntReady`) :

```
    private void OnFrameReceived(Frame frame)
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;

        if (true == m_Acquiring)
        {
            mycamera.QueueFrame(frame);
        }

        frame.Fill(ref myBitmap);
        pictureBoxLiveCamera.Image = myBitmap;
        SaveBitmap = myBitmap.Clone(cloneRect, myBitmap.PixelFormat);

        Array.Clear(PixelColorCount, 0, 256);
        unsafe
        {
            int width = SaveBitmap.Width;
            int height = SaveBitmap.Height;
            int bytesPerPixel = 1;
            int maxPointerLength = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
            int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bData = SaveBitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, SaveBitmap.Width, SaveBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, SaveBitmap.PixelFormat);
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();
            byte B;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxPointerLength; i++)
            {
                B = scan0[i];
                PixelColorCount[B] += 1;
            }
            SaveBitmap.UnlockBits(bData);
        }

        PixelColorCountReady = PixelColorCount.DeepClone();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use multiple threads. Everytime you get an image => run thread that will collect data to global variable. Add another thread to read this variable every few moments and draw chart from it. All this can be done from one form

Comment: THis honestly is a good idea I hadn't think of. As I have never used multi-threading (kind of a newb with C# and coding as a whole), do you know a good newb-friendly document I could read about it ? Anyway, thanks for the idea, I'll be looking into it.

Comment: This just for a [start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will find many answers here on SO.  I like to keep it simple but you will need to learn little about delegates to update GUI from another thread [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to close your thread (the one plotting chart) when you [close](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3e443e1-09a0-435a-8124-6fc19d9bd759/best-way-to-stop-a-thread?forum=csharpgeneral) a program.